# Перенос проекта-Laravel на хостинг

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, hosting

Как перенести на хостинг веб-приложение созданное на **Laravel 5.4**?

Есть вариант: `SSH` (никогда им не пользовался, можете дать любу информацию о нем) или же обычный `FTP`, но с учетом того, что корневая папка сайта - `public_html.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой перенос сайта через SSH:

```
ssh user@your_old_server # Подключится по SSH
tar -czf /home/user/website.tar.gz full_path_to_public_html # Создать архив сайта
exit # отключится
ssh root@your_new_server # подключится к новому сайту
cd your_new_public_html # перейти в public_html
scp user@your_old_server:/home/user/website.tar.gz ./ # Подключится к старому серверу и скачать с него архив
tar -xzf website.tar.gz ./ # распаковать сюда же
rm website.tar.gz # удалить после распаковки
```

Однако, правильный способ - это поместить исходный код в GIT и настроить автодеплой. Пользовательские загрузки (uploads) же скопировать напрямую через SSH.

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать rsync. вот [тут](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/deploy-with-rsync) есть инструкция для настройки выгрузки. сам его использую на нескольких проектах